# Using Wordpress XML-RPC wp.uploadFile and wp.newPost from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm using Wordpress XML-RPC to automatically post to my blog and I got these two functions working from PHP: wp.newPost and wp.uploadFile.

However, when I run them in one php script as shown below: (just included the important parts) Wordpress is not detecting attachment_id from wp.uploadFile when I try to post even though attachment_id exists.

```
//wp.newPost content
$content = array(
'post_title' => $title,
'post_content' => $body,
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'post_type' => 'products',
'post_thumbnail' = // wp.uploadFile is called here that returns attachement id
);

$this->Curl->post($url,$content);
```

When I try to run above code I get: " faultCode 404 faultString Invalid attachment ID. "

I verified that the wp.uploadFile image has been uploaded successfully and its showing in the Wordpress library. In fact, if I run the script again and just replace the 'post_thumbnail' value with the same exact attachement_id that was return by wp.uploadFile, it works!

So, apparently Wordpress is not detecting that the image has been uploaded if I run the two functions in conjunction as shown above. Is there any solution to this? I would really hate to store Wordpress attachement id's in my own database.

Answer (score 2):

to post via xmlrpc i'm using IXR

```
require_once("IXR_Library.php.inc");
```

the below is what i'm using; it will need certainly some edits but might give you some clue

to upload a new file:

```
$file_upload_path = get_post_meta ( $image->ID,'_wp_attached_file', false);
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dev/0.2/wp-content/uploads/".$file_upload_path[0];
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_name = $path_parts['filename'].'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
$data = array(
  'name'  => $file_name ,
  'type'  => $image->post_mime_type ,
  'bits'  => new IXR_Base64( file_get_contents( $file_path ) ) ,
  'overwrite' => true
);
$status = $rpc->query(
    'wp.uploadFile', 
    '1',
    $username,
    $password,
    $data
);
$image_returnInfo = $rpc->getResponse();
```

to create a new post:

```
$data = array(
    'post_title' => $post->post_title,
    'post_content' => $post->post_content . $attachement_string_hack,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'dateCreated' => (new IXR_Date(time())),
    'post_thumbnail' => $image_returnInfo['id']
);
$rpc = new IXR_Client( $rpc_url );
$res = $rpc->query('wp.newPost', '', $username, $password, $data, 0);
```

hope this helps!
(i'm now stuck with attaching images to post)

Comment: I got it to work, it was a problem was my regex. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Are you using a theme that allows you to attach images as posts? If so, attach the image to a post manually and then check what the meta_key is in wp_postmeta table then use that key in custom_fields of $data in this format: $data = array('custom_fields' => array(array('key' => 'meta_key_name', 'value' => 'your image url'));

Comment: Walter - thanks, i need the images to be attached so they appear as 'attached' in the media library: i need the post parent column to be accessible via xmlrpc. apparently, from my last reading last night, it's not available in the current version of wp (3.4.2)

Comment: just in case you end up in similar trouble with image attachement: wp needs the 22335 patch; as per this ticket http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22335